# only the first image I am bringing from database is appearing

Tags: php

I'm having a strange error, and I know Im posting a lot of code, but, Im really not understanding what Im doing wrong, so I decided to put all the code here related to my problem.

I also commented my code to be easily to understand context.

The problem is:

Im bringing my news information from database,  and Im having a problem with images, only the image of the first post, which is the recent news, is appearing, the others dont appear.

However if I delete the code that I quoted like ***FROM HERE**** ****TO HERE***, images appear correctly.

Someone there realize why this is happening in this code excerpt that causes the images of my news do not appear?

```
<div id="content">
    <h1>News</h1>
    <?php
    //first I read my news
    $readNews = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM news WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0,4");
    $readNews->execute();
    //while exist news I want to read category of that news, and show news info in my article
    while ($readNewsResult  = $readNews->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $readCat=  $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM categories , news WHERE id_cat = ?");
        $readCat->bindValue(1,$readNewsResult['category']);
        $readCat->execute();
        $resultReadCat = $readCat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        //I show news info in my article                    
        echo '<article class="loop-news">'; 
            echo '<img src="'.$path.$readNewsResult['thumb'].'" />';
            echo '<h2><a href="#">'.$readNewsResult['title'].'</a><br /></h2>'; 
            echo '<span>'.$resultNewsResult['date'].'</span>';
            echo '<p>'.$readNewsResult['content'].'<a id="'.$readNewsResult['id_not'].'" class="fancybox" href="#show'.$readNewsResult['id_not'].'">See more</a></p>';      

        //I repeat my news info to show inside fancybox
        echo '<div class="show-container">';
            echo '<div id="show'.$readNewsResult['id_news'].'">';
                echo '<h2>'.$readNewsResult['title'].'</h2>';
                echo '<span>'.$resultNewsResult['date'].'</span>';
                echo '<img src="'.$path.$readNewsResult['thumb'].'" />';
                echo '<p>'.$readNewsResult['content'].'</p>';


                //******************FROM HERE***************************/
                //I read my table links_news to see if news that is reading have links associated
                $readLinks =  $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM links_news WHERE news_id = ?");
                $readLinks->bindValue(1,$readNewsResult['id_news']);
                $readLinks->execute();

                //if current reading news have links it will show on my links div
                echo '<div  class="links">';
                    echo '<h3>Relative Links:</h3>';
                    echo '<ul class="links1">';
                    while ($readLinksResult = $readLinks->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                    {
                    echo '<li> <a href="'.$path.$readLinksResult['link'].'">'.$readLinksResult['link'].'</a></li>';

                    }
                    echo '</ul>';

                echo '</div>';<!-- close class links-->
                //****************TO HERE*******************/
            echo '</div>';<!-- close class show -->
        echo '</div>';<!-- close  class show-container-->
        echo '</article>';
    }
    ?>      
</div>
```

Comment: i have no clue how PDO works but this line is suspicious to me:   $readLinks->bindValue(1,$readNewsResult['id_news']);   should it be:    $readLinks->bindValue(1,$readLinksResult['id_news']); ???

Comment: Thanks for your answer user3132781. And no, because I want to show links where id_news it is icual to id of the news that I have read previously.

Comment: you're running nested queries. that's always a sign of bad design. you should have a SINGLE `join`ed query.